# greediness in sed

Tags: regex, shell, sed, greedy

I want

```
ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat)
```

to become

```
preg_match ('#'.$rat.'#', $dog, $cat)
```

To achieve this, I did

```
echo 'ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat)' | sed "s/ereg\(.*\)(\(.*\),/preg_match\1('#'.\2.'#',/g"
```

but, this regex changed the

```
ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat)
```

into

```
preg_match ('#'.$rat, $dog.'#', $cat)
```

instead of

```
preg_match ('#'.$rat.'#', $dog, $cat)
```

Can someone help me to build a regex that changes

```
ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat)
```

into

```
preg_match ('#'.$rat.'#', $dog, $cat)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just exclude ','...

```
echo 'ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat)' | sed "s/ereg\(.*\)(\([^,]*\),/preg_match\1('#'.\2.'#',/g"
```

Comment: thanks. i am using this: echo 'ereg ( ($rat), $dog, $cat)' | sed "s/ereg\([^\(]*\)(\([^,]*\),/preg_match\1('#'.\2.'#',/g"

Answer (score 2):

*Note:* This also works if you have multiple instances of `ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat)` on the same line whereas other answers do not:

```
$ echo 'ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat)' | sed "s/ereg\([^(]*\)(\([^,]*\),\([^)]*)\)/preg_match\1('#'.\2.'#',\3/g"
preg_match ('#'.$rat.'#', $dog, $cat)
```

#### Example

```
$ echo 'ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat) ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat)' | sed "s/ereg\([^(]*\)(\([^,]*\),\([^)]*)\)/preg_match\1('#'.\2.'#',\3/g"
preg_match ('#'.$rat.'#', $dog, $cat) preg_match ('#'.$rat.'#', $dog, $cat)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
~ ross$ echo 'ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat)' | sed -e "s/.*(\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^)]*\))/preg_match ('#'.\1.'#', \2, \3)/"
preg_match ('#'.$rat.'#',  $dog,  $cat)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$ echo 'ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat)' | sed "s/ereg *(\([^,]*\), \([^,]*\)\([^)]*\))/preg_match('#'.\1.'#', \2\3)/g"
preg_match('#'.$rat.'#', $dog, $cat)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using this. echo 'ereg ( ($rat), $dog, $cat)' | sed "s/ereg\([^\(]*\)(\([^,]*\),/preg_match\1('#'.\2.'#',/g"

Answer (score 0):

I rather like Perl regexs (easier to write):

```
echo 'ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat)' | perl -pe 's/ereg\s*\(\s*(\$[^,]+),(.+)\)/preg_match("#" . $1 . "#", $2)/g'
```

or better (for PHP):

```
echo 'ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat)' | perl -pe 's/ereg\s*\(\s*(\$[^,]+),(.+)\)/preg_match("#{$1}#", $2)/g'
```

In *sed*, it would be:

```
echo 'ereg ($rat, $dog, $cat)' | sed -e 's/ereg\s*(\s*\(\$[^,]\+\),\(.\+\))/preg_match("#" . \1 . "#", \2)/'
```

Too many backslashes!!!