# script to search and replace deprecated functions

Tags: regex, shell, sed, deprecated

I am using the following script to search and replace the deprecated functions in a file with the newer ones.

```
  5 for strFile in `ls deprecated_functions_search_and_replace.txt `
  6 do
  7     sed "s/ereg_replace[^\(]*(\([^,]*\),/preg_replace\1('#'.\2.'#',/g"  $strFile > temp_file
  8     mv $strFile $strFile".bakup"
  9     mv temp_file $strFile
 10
 11     sed "s/eregi[^\(]*(\([^,]*\),/preg_match\1('#'.\2.'#i',/g" $strFile > temp_file
 12     mv $strFile $strFile".bakup"
 13     mv temp_file $strFile
 14
 15     sed "s/ereg[^\(]*(\([^,]*\),/preg_match\1('#'.\2.'#',/g" $strFile > temp_file
 16     mv $strFile $strFile".bakup"
 17     mv temp_file $strFile
 18
 19     sed "s/split[^\(]*(\([^,]*\),/preg_split\1('#'.\2.'#',/g" $strFile > temp_file
 20     mv $strFile $strFile".bakup"
 21     mv temp_file $strFile
 22
 23     sed "s/mysql_escape_string/mysql_real_escape_string/g" $strFile > temp_file
 24     mv $strFile $strFile".bakup"
 25     mv temp_file $strFile
 26
 27     sed "s/set_magic_quotes_runtime(0)/\/\/set_magic_quotes_runtime(0)/g" $strFile > temp_file
 28     mv $strFile $strFile".bakup"
 29     mv temp_file $strFile
 30
 31     sed "s/ini_get('safe_mode')/false/g" $strFile > temp_file
 32     mv $strFile $strFile".bakup"
 33     mv temp_file $strFile
 34
 35     sed "s/session_register('\(.*\)')/$_SESSION['\1']=$\1/g" $strFile > temp_file
 36     mv $strFile $strFile".bakup"
 37     mv temp_file $strFile
 38
 39     sed "s/session_unregister('\(.*\)')/$_SESSION['\1']=''/g" $strFile > temp_file
 40     mv $strFile $strFile".bakup"
 41     mv temp_file $strFile
 42
 43 done
```

However, when I run this script I am getting an error saying:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 60: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
sed: -e expression #1, char 52: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
sed: -e expression #1, char 50: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
sed: -e expression #1, char 51: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS
```

I am unable to figure out whats going wrong. Someone please help me. Regards.

Comment: sed is telling you that you're using `\2` when you only have 1 pair of capturing parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't copy [**my `sed` script correctly**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684760/greediness-in-sed/4684843#4684843)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know sed today, but it looks like grouping parenths are special char's when escaped, literal otherwise. I'm also not sure on the replacement side where its usually literal and here the capture groups look like they are backslashed.

So using the example of the session_register, it appears to be missing a capture group.
This would seem to be the fix:   `s/ereg_replace\([^(]*\)(\([^,]*\),/preg_replace\1('#'.\2.'#',/g"`